# OenStack cinder failure

Tags: openstack, crash, cinder

We have a cluster based on OpenStack Rocky, and it was working fine until we added some compute nodes and `ceph`.

Now we have some issue with Cinder stability. Cinder is crashing during every rally test and even when the rally test is done or not executed. We searched in the log files and found no signs of error or failure messages.
Any ideas why?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you enable verbose logging on Cinder services and post the output? You can set `debug = True` in `/var/log/cinder.conf` in the controller and restart cinder services (e.g. `cinder-api` and `cinder-scheduler`) before monitoring the logs again; likewise, set `debug = True` in `/var/log/cinder.conf` in the compute nodes (restart `cinder-volume`). You might then be able to see error messages. If you see some error messages, post your results here to help others in debugging.